# How to select values in a multiple DropDownList using DropdownListFor in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2, dropdownlistfor

I have this model:

```
public class CampoTipoDocumentoViewModel
{
    public int TipoDocumentoId { get; set; }

    public string[] CamposId { get; set; }

    private List<MiddleTier.Models.ICampo> _todosCampos;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TodosCampos
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var campo in _todosCampos)
                yield return new SelectListItem { Text = campo.Nombre, Value = campo.Id.ToString() };
        }
    }  

    public void SetFields(List<MiddleTier.Models.ICampo> campos)
    {
        _todosCampos = campos;
    }
}
```

In controller, CamposId property is assigned with elements which has to be selected in the view.

Controller also calls SetFields method populating _todosCampos to the whole list of records in the system.

The idea is to create a View with a SELECT that has initially some records selected.

This is my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CamposId, Model.TodosCampos, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", width = "100%" })
```

The fact is that the HTML SELECT element is created with the list, but no option is selected.

For example, if _todosCampos contains:

```
Text = "One", Value = "1"
Text = "Two", Value = "2"
Text = "Three", Value = "3"
Text = "Four", Value = "4"
```

and CamposId contains:

```
Array of "2", "4"
```

I need the view to create a SELECT with those 4 options, and option 2 and 4 to be initially selected.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `<select>` element with `multiple="multiple"` attribute, you need to declare `List<string>` property:

```
public List<string> CamposId { get; set; }
```

And then use `ListBoxFor` helper instead of `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CamposId, Model.TodosCampos, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", width = "100%" })
```

If you want to set some option values are selected by default, then set `Selected` property into `SelectListItem`:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TodosCampos
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var campo in _todosCampos)
        {
            // assumed you have 'campo.IsDefault' which is boolean property 
            yield return new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = campo.Nombre, 
                Value = campo.Id.ToString(), 
                Selected = campo.IsDefault // set default selected values
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Usually ID property contain integer values, you can try for `List<int> CamposId` depending on actual ID data type in database.

Comment: Thanks.. I have only changed property type to List<string> and used ListBoxFor instead and it worked. It automatically selected the elements.